# Proof about diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

show that the diophantine equation $$x^2-y^2=N$$

is solvable in nonnegative integers x and y if and only if N is odd or divisible  by 4. Show further that the solution is unique if and only if $|N|$ or $|N|/4$ respectively is unity or a prime.

I am stuck in the first part in regards to validity.

$$x^2-y^2=4$$ and there is no nonnegative integers $x,y$ that satisfy the equation.

Comment: Take $x=2$ and ,$y=0$.

Comment: $2^2-0^2=4$, since you said "nonnegative".

Comment: so 0 is non negative?. 0 is neither positive nor negative.

Comment: For $N=1$ this is Pell's equation with $d=1$.

Comment: @TheMathNoob You said yourself that $0$ is not negative (nor positive)... Of course that makes it **non** negative.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ The (non) uniqueness follows from a composition law for *differences* of squares

$\rm\qquad\qquad\ (a^2-b^2)\ (A^2-B^2)\ =\ (a\:A+b\:B)^2-(a\:B+A\:b)^2$

$\rm\qquad\qquad\ \phantom{(a^2-b^2)\ (A^2-B^2)}\ =\ (a\:A-b\:B)^2-(a\:B-A\:b)^2$

E.g. $ $ composing $\rm\ 7 = 4^2 - 3^2\ $ with $\ 11 = 6^2 - 5^2\ $ yields two rep's for $\rm\: 7\cdot 11\:$

$\rm\qquad\qquad\ (4^2-3^2)\ (6^2-5^2)\ =\ (4\cdot 6+3\cdot 5)^2-(4\cdot 5+6\cdot 3)^2 =\ 39^2 - 38^2$

$\rm\qquad\qquad\ \phantom{(4^2-3^2)\ (6^2-5^2)}\ =\ (4\cdot 6-3\cdot 5)^2-(4\cdot 5-6\cdot 3)^2 =\ 9^2 - 2^2$

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$, we know the difference between these two factors is $2y$.  Only a number of the form $2m$, where $m$ is odd, has no factor pairs whose difference is even, so all other numbers can be expressed as a difference of two squares.